# Sailsjs overwrite post action in controller

Tags: sails.js

Short question, tried finding an IRC for sails for such a quick one but got lost so here goes. I have a controller with a route of '/userposts'. I know sails offers some default REST-like functionality without backend code needed but what if I want to overwrite the default POST action what would I do?

I'm forced to write a POST route such as `post /userposts/create` or I can overwrite the default action and post straight to `/userposts` which will identify my overwriting and execute it.

I hope I'm making sense. I basically want to create a custom POST route and be able to

```
socket.post('/userposts', {title: "Foo", content: "Bar"}, function(response){});
```

I tried with `create` but it doesn't get executed on a post to `/userposts`

Answer (score 3):

Sails.js provides blueprints out of the box.

These blueprints provide you with the following **CRUD** routes that are enabled by default

```
/:controller/find/:id?
/:controller/create
/:controller/update/:id
/:controller/destroy/:id
```

To modify the default functionality for your controllers, look at the settings in *config/controllers.js*

Your routes are defined within *config/routes.js*, in your case you have a model *UserPosts* and a corresponding controller named *UserPostsController*.

In your *UserPosts* controller, create a function *createPost* and specify the route(s) to this method

```
'POST /userposts/create': 'UserPostsController.createPost'
```

which is shorthand for

```
'POST /userposts/create': {
  controller: 'userposts',
  action: 'createPost'
}
```

you can also override the /:controller route

```
'POST /userposts': 'UserPostsController.createPost'
```

These routes will map any POST requests made to the *createPost* function.

For more information, be sure to check out the [Sails.js documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation)

Comment: Is there anyway to tell what the requested verb is from within the controller's action function?

Comment: @MrBell Sure: `req.method`.